# How to install previous version of spacy

Tags: spacy-3

I am trying to train a custom model in spacy but the new update has totally changed how it must be done. Is there any way to download a previous version of spacy on anaconda e.g. spacy 3.0.6

Answer (score 1):

You can download old versions the same way you do with any package.

```
conda install spacy==3.0.6
```

Note that spaCy training did not change significantly between 3.0.6 and the latest 3.1.3. Perhaps you wanted to use v2?

Comment: How do you do that for MAC computers? Running `pip install spacy[apple]` ( [source](https://spacy.io/usage/v3-2) ) installs the latest version available (at the moment of writing this, V3.4.2; I would like to install for instance V3.2.1).

Comment: Specifying versions works the same on OSX as it does on other operating systems. It would be like `spacy[apple]==3.2.1`.

Comment: The previous suggestion has led me to a new error. I have opened a new Stack Overflow question, please find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185326/install-old-spacy-release-in-a-mac-computer). Let's continue there, thanks.