# Install old spaCy release in a MAC computer

Tags: python, pip, spacy-3

I would like to install spaCy V3.2.1 in my virtual environment (MacBook Air, Apple M1 processor, MACOs Ventura 13.0). The commands I run, inspired by [the spaCy widget](https://spacy.io/usage) and [the specific information for Apple computers](https://spacy.io/usage/v3-2), are:

```bash
# Create and activate virtual environment
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

# Install latest pip version
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Install spaCy with my needed requirements
pip install setuptools wheel
pip install -U 'spacy[apple]'==3.2.1
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

The previous commands get me the following error:

```bash
1 error generated.
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for spacy
Failed to build spacy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for spacy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

**UPDATE:** The full error can be **temporarily** found [here](https://github.com/dave-espinosa/appleM1spacyerror/blob/main/myerror).

If I run `pip install -U 'spacy[apple]'` alone, this will (successfully) install spaCy V3.4.3, which is the latest release when this post was written, BUT this is NOT what I am looking for.

**IMPORTANT:** It is preferred to install spaCy V3.2.1 via `pip`, however not mandatory (i.e., as long as I have that spaCy version installed in `venv` and can be successfully imported from Python scripts, it will work for me).

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full error output, not just the final line, as it's not clear what the actual error is. What Python version are you using? Can you run `pip install spacy==3.2.1`?

Comment: @polm23 done. Please have a check and let me know your thoughts, thanks.

Comment: OK, so the important part of your error is that `Python.h` isn't found, so spaCy can't be built from source. I am not very familiar with Macs but it sounds like you may need to update Xcode, including the "command line tools". It's necessary to build spaCy from source because we didn't have M1 wheels for 3.2, but they should be usable from 3.3. (Why do you need 3.2?)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. BTW, I opened this case on behalf of another colleague, I'll make sure he's aware of your suggestion. As to "why we're using `spacy==3.2.1`?", it's because we have some NER model in that version, and since we need to make some quick tests with it, retraining a new model with the most up-to-date spaCy versión, is not feasible at the moment. I hope to get back at this thread with news soon.

Comment: Your model will probably work with newer versions? It's safer to use the same version but test it and see if you have any issues, it's probably fine.

Comment: Hello @polm23, and sorry for the wait. Conclusions: 1) By updating OS to `macOS Ventura`, Xcode got implicitely updated, which solved the original error; 2) Running a spaCy model trained with V3.2.1, from V3.4.3 (most up-to-date at the moment of writing), triggered a warning, but allowed to retrieve entities from texts successfully, so it could be used as emergency workaround. It's important to stress that we've only used the `ner` component, so we cannot ensure the function of other components is _"100% OK"_ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment section, the error got solved after upgrading OS to `macOS Ventura 13`, which implicitely upgraded `Xcode` to version `14.1`.